# How to specify argparse default file when type=argparse.FileType

Tags: python, argparse

I'm attempting to allow an optional argument that takes a single command line argument of a filename:

```
parser.add_argument('--somefile', nargs=1, type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                     required=False, default='defaultfile.json')
```

The problem is when I specify a file using the `--somefile foo.json` I get back a handle in a list:

```
args.somefile=[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='foo.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
```

When I don't specify it and want the default, I get back a handle, but not in a list:

```
args.somefile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='defaultfile.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

How do I get args.somefile to return the same type of structure (handle either in a list or not in a list) consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) argument.

> Note that `nargs=1` produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

**UPDATE on comment**

> Removing `nargs=1` would eliminate the requirement to specify the filename argument.

Lets check:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--somefile', type=argparse.FileType('r'), required=False, default='/tmp/data.json')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--somefile'], dest='somefile', nargs=None, const=None, default='/tmp/data.json', type=FileType('r'), choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--somefile',])
usage: [-h] [--somefile SOMEFILE]
: error: argument --somefile: expected one argument
```

Comment: Removing `nargs=1` would eliminate the requirement to specify the filename argument.

Comment: @Omniver, no, its not. Check it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not read far enough in the documentation.  'nargs - The number of command-line arguments that should be consumed.'  Later though: 'ArgumentParser objects **usually associate a single command-line argument with a single action to be taken**. The nargs keyword argument associates a different number of command-line arguments with a single action.'